# アコーディオンメニューが意図した通り動作しない

Tags: html, css

ボタンを押すとアコーディオンメニューが開くようにプログラムを組んだつもりなのですが、うまく動きません。

```css
.menu {
    max-width: 600px;
}

.menu a {
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}

label {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 4px 0;
    padding : 15px;
    line-height: 1;
    color :#fff;
    background : white;
    cursor :pointer;
}

input {
    display: none;
}

.menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background :white;
    list-style: none;
}

.menu li {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

#menu_bar01:checked ~ #links01 li{
    height: 54px;
    opacity: 1;
}


*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

/* 背景用*/
body {
  padding: -5px;
}

.btn,
a.btn,
button.btn {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.5;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1rem 4rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  color: #212529;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  margin: 10px 20px 30px 40px; /* 外側の時計回りの余白 */
}

a.btn-border-shadow5 {
  padding: calc(1.5rem - 12px) 3rem 1.5rem;

  background: red;
}

a.btn-border-shadow5:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  left: -6px;

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  content: "";
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;

  border: 3px solid #000;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

a.btn-border-shadow5:hover {
  padding: calc(1.5rem - 6px) 3rem;
}

a.btn-border-shadow5:hover:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

/* 背景用*/
body {
  padding: -5px;
}

.btn,
a.btn,
button.btn {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.5;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1rem 4rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  color: #212529;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  margin: 10px 20px 30px 40px; /* 外側の時計回りの余白 */
}

a.btn-border-shadow6 {
  padding: calc(1.5rem - 12px) 3rem 1.5rem;

  background: blue;
}

a.btn-border-shadow6:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  left: -6px;

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  content: "";
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;

  border: 3px solid #000;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

a.btn-border-shadow6:hover {
  padding: calc(1.5rem - 6px) 3rem;
}

a.btn-border-shadow6:hover:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

/* 背景用*/
body {
  padding: -5px;
}

.btn,
a.btn,
button.btn {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.5;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1rem 4rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  color: #212529;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  margin: 10px 20px 30px 40px; /* 外側の時計回りの余白 */
}

a.btn-border-shadow7 {
  padding: calc(1.5rem - 12px) 3rem 1.5rem;

  background: green;
}

a.btn-border-shadow7:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  left: -6px;

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  content: "";
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;

  border: 3px solid #000;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

a.btn-border-shadow7:hover {
  padding: calc(1.5rem - 6px) 3rem;
}

a.btn-border-shadow7:hover:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

/* 背景用*/
body {
  padding: -5px;
}

.btn,
a.btn,
button.btn {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.5;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1rem 4rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  color: #212529;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  margin: 10px 20px 30px 40px; /* 外側の時計回りの余白 */
}

a.btn-border-shadow8 {
  padding: calc(1.5rem - 12px) 3rem 1.5rem;

  background: yellow;
}

a.btn-border-shadow8:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  left: -6px;

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  content: "";
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;

  border: 3px solid #000;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

a.btn-border-shadow8:hover {
  padding: calc(1.5rem - 6px) 3rem;
}

a.btn-border-shadow8:hover:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

/* 背景用*/
body {
  padding: -5px;
}

.btn,
a.btn,
button.btn {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.5;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1rem 4rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  color: #212529;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  margin: 10px 20px 30px 40px; /* 外側の時計回りの余白 */
}

a.btn-border-shadow {
  padding: calc(1.5rem - 12px) 3rem 1.5rem;

  background: #ffff00;
}

a.btn-border-shadow:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  left: -6px;

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  content: "";
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;

  border: 3px solid #000;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

a.btn-border-shadow:hover {
  padding: calc(1.5rem - 6px) 3rem;
}

a.btn-border-shadow:hover:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<td>
     <label for="menu_bar01"><a href="" class="btn btn-border-shadow">小学校</a></label>
  </td>
  <input type="checkbox" id="menu_bar01" />
  <ul id="links01">
    <divclass="btn-wrap5"><a href="" class="btn btn-border-shadow5">国語</a></div>
    <divclass="btn-wrap6"><a href="" class="btn btn-border-shadow6">算数</a></div>
    <divclass="btn-wrap7"><a href="" class="btn btn-border-shadow7">理科</a></div>
    <divclass="btn-wrap8"><a href="" class="btn btn-border-shadow8">社会</a></div>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: いただいたHTMLが正しいものではなさそうです。divの閉じタグが余計だったり、空白がなかったり、CSSも同じような内容が二重に書かれているようです。以下を参考に再度質問を組みたたてください[再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

レイアウトが違うけど、ボタンのリンクがアコーディオンに見えますね。

試しにアコーディオンメニュー書いてみました。

```css
.accordion {
    max-width: 360px;
    margin: 20;
    padding: 10;
}
.accordion a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
    line-height: 1;
}
.accordion label {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 0 2px 0;
    padding: 12px;
    line-height: 1;
    color: black;
    background: yellow;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.accordion label::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '+';
    color: black;
    right: 0.5em;
    top: 25%;
}
.accordion input {
    display: none;
}
.accordion ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #f4f4f4;
    list-style: none;
}
.accordion li {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    max-height: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

#accordion_bar1:checked ~ #link1 li,
#accordion_bar2:checked ~ #link2 li {
    max-height: 46px;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="accordion.css">
<div class="accordion">
<label for="accordion_bar1">小学校</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="accordion_bar1" class="accordion" />
<ul id="link1">
    <li><a href="">国語</a></li>
    <li><a href="">算数</a></li>
    <li><a href="">理科</a></li>
    <li><a href="">社会</a></li>
</ul>
<label for="accordion_bar2">学習塾</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="accordion_bar2" class="accordion" />
<ul id="link2">
    <li><a href="">国語</a></li>
    <li><a href="">算数</a></li>
    <li><a href="">理科</a></li>
    <li><a href="">社会</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```